# Authentication middleware without password

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I have a table with employees, customers, person, sales and others (this is for details about people like email, address, etc).

- The `person` table has columns like `name, address,` etc
- The `employees` table has columns `person_id, password`
- The `customer` table has columns `person_id`

Now, I have an authentication middleware to check if an employee is logged in, but in this case the customers doesn't use the system because the employees just use the customer data for register with a sale.

My question is makes sense have authorization middleware?

PS: Sorry for my English.